# Test question difficulty

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The African American painter Jacob Lawrence has frequently used the series format as a way to tell a story. As in narrative series painted by such earlier masters as Giotto, Goya, Daumier, and Orozco, the images on different panels in Lawrence’s series are designed with a deliberate continuity of style and color. The strength of the series resides in the way the panels reinforce and enhance each other visually and dramatically. Lawrence differs from earlier series painters not in the narrative power of the series, but in the kinds of subjects he chooses to dramatize. In choosing topics for his series, Lawrence often takes inspiration from the stories his community tells about its heritage. His series Harriet Tubman (1939-40), for example, recounts the story of the escaped slave who helped liberate over 300 slaves through the Underground Railroad. In this series and others, Lawrence provides a prose caption for each painting, often written in a storytelling style reminiscent of the African American oral tradition.

The question is:

> According to the passage. Lawrence’s series differ most widely from those of some earlier painters in which of the following aspects? 
>   (A) Source of this content depicted an the panels 
>   (B) Continuity of style among panels 
>   (C) Reinforcement of visual effect from panel to panel 
>   (D) Congruity of color among panels 
>   (E) Mutual dramatic enhancement among panels

The answer is (a).

I don't catch it. As I see it, the sentence that should answer it is:

> Lawrence differs from earlier series … but in the kinds of subjects he chooses to dramatize.

Hence I think it should be (C) or (E).  Can someone explain me why the answer is (a)?

Comment: The answer is in the question sentence: *content* (the subjects). If you do not understand the difference between content and the other words, you need to look in a dictionary. This is really an easy one.

Comment: You were very close. You might have been over thinking it. You could also have approached this through process of elimination. But yea, the subjects you choose to dramatize would be the content of your work.

Comment: Is your question about the meaning of "but"? What do you understand the sentence "Lawrence differs from earlier series … but in the kinds of subjects he chooses to dramatize" to mean? (Note: it is not a correctly formed sentence. The correct way of abbreviating the sentence from the text would be Lawrence differs from earlier series … in the kinds of subjects he chooses to dramatize.")

Answer (score 1):

I think that sumelic's comment above gets at the only basis that I can see for the poster's confusion—namely, that he or she doesn't see how to parse the embedded parenthetical phrase "not in the narrative power of the series, but" properly. If, like the poster, you see the main sentence as being

> Lawrence differs from earlier series [painters] … but in the kinds of subjects he chooses to dramatize.

you might be confused as to the significance of the word *but*—especially if you somehow take it to mean "but not." As sumelic observes, however, *but* is part of the presentation of the parenthetical (the broken-out idea), not the first word after it. That is, the main sentence is

> Lawrence differs from earlier series painters ... in the kinds of subjects he chooses to dramatize.

The alternative difference, which the author of the excerpt parenthetically proposes and rejects, is

> in the narrative power of the series

and the words *not* and *but* at each end of this clause seal it off from the rest of the sentence, like book ends enclosing the parenthetical idea.

Comment: Very well stated!